# Select a column's data in a group and place in new column across entire group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to select a column's data in a group and place that data in its own column for each row of the group.

Specifically, if I've got a table that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobtable
JOBNum | ReqDateTime             | RowNum
-------+----------+------
 M210  | 2015-01-08 17:01:56.000 | 1
 M214  | 2015-01-12 17:46:09.000 | 1
 M214  | 2015-01-16 20:19:43.000 | 2 
 M219  | 2015-01-27 15:05:16.000 | 1
 M219  | 2015-01-28 02:01:13.000 | 2
```

I want to show this:

```
JOBNum | ReqDateTime             | FirstDateInEachGroup    | Row |                                  
-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----+
 M210  | 2015-01-08 17:01:56.000 | 2015-01-08 17:01:56.000 | 1   | 
 M214  | 2015-01-12 17:46:09.000 | 2015-01-12 17:46:09.000 | 1   | 
 M214  | 2015-01-16 20:19:43.000 | 2015-01-12 17:46:09.000 | 2   | 
 M219  | 2015-01-27 15:05:16.000 | 2015-01-27 15:05:16.000 | 1   | 
 M219  | 2015-01-28 02:01:13.000 | 2015-01-27 15:05:16.000 | 2   |
```

I want create another column "FirstDateInEachGroup" on the fly which consists of the ReqDateTime which is in each JobNum group with the Row = 1.  In the above example you can see that where there are two JobNum's that are the same they have a different "Row", andthe FirstDateInEachGroup would contain the same data in each row with the same JobNum.

How do I do this without using a cursor or function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    JobNum, ReqDateTime, RowNum,
    (select min(ReqDateTime) from JobTable jt2 where jt2.JobNum = jt1.JobNum group by JobNum) as FirstDateInEachGroup
FROM Jobtable jt1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `min()` window function:

```
SELECT JobNum, ReqDateTime,
       MIN(ReqDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY JobNum) as FirstDateInEachGroup,
       RowNum
FROM Jobtable;
```